# Remove Nuget Package when feed url is no longer available

Tags: nuget

I have a project that uses a package that is no longer available.
When trying to restore the packages I get and error.
When trying to remove the packages using the "Manage Nuget Packages" windows it fails because the feed is no longer available.

How do I remove this package even though the feed is no longer available?

Comment: I finally resorted to manually removing the dlls that belong to the package. I wonder if there is an easier way to remove the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have access to the original NuGet package (.nupkg) then unfortunately the only way to do this is to manually remove the reference information from the project file and the packages.config file.

NuGet requires the original NuGet package (.nupkg) so it can determine what files should be removed from the project when the NuGet package is uninstalled.